# How to use IDataReader with XmlReader for SqlCeBulkCopy?

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-ce, idatareader

I have large XML file (2 Gb) and I need import data to sql ce db. XML file have a root tag and many same tags with 20 attributes (like a 2d table):

```
<Objects>
<Object ID="" name="" level="" />
<Object ID="" name="" level="" />
```

For load data from XML to sql ce db I use `SqlCeBulkCopy` (on [codeplex](https://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/)). I try use `DataTable`, but have this error (becouse XML is more then 2 Gb):

> "System.OutOfMemoryException"

I use `XmlReader` to read information from XML file:

```
XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create("file:////" + PathToFile);
  while (r.Read())
    {
        if ((r.Name == "Object") && (r.HasAttributes))
        {

        }
    }
```

And how use `IDataReader` with `XmlReader` for `SqlCeBulkCopy` in this situation (any example)?

Answer (score 1):

xmlReader and DbDataReader are not related. But SqlCeBulkcopy supports both List and DataTable objects as well as DbDataReader

Use a List, and only load say 10000 rows/records, then bulk copy those and continue. You cannot fit a 2 GB XML file into memory!

So outside your while loop add (pseudo code):

```
var list = new List<MyObjects>();
```

And inside your while loop add:

```
var myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.Property1 = value from xmlreader;
myObject.Property2 = anotherValue from xmlreader;

list.Add(myObject);

if (list.Count == 10000)
{
   //run BulkCopy
   list.Clear();
}
```

Comment: I about `IDataREader` for example `public class CustomObjectDataReader : IDataReader` and in this use `XmlReader`

Comment: Why make it so difficult for yourself?

Comment: @ErikEJ, hi there. It is 2019. Do you still think that your implementation is better than implementing the `IDataReader`? I am just faced with the same issue and can not decide what is better - to implement the `IDataReader` or to follow your answer.

Comment: What do you think my answer to your question would be?

Comment: @ErikEJ, I thought that your answer posted above is still relevant. So, I used it in my current implementation. Is it the case here, is your answer still relevant? :)